# Running g++ on Solaris

Tags: unix, gcc, g++, solaris

Every time I try to compile a program I've written in C++ on Solaris, I get this very odd and extensive error message. As a test, I created the most basic C++ program I could come up with:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9oyU.png]

This program compiles just fine using g++ on my Mac under the Mac OS, but I can't seem to be able to run it on Solaris. Does anybody have any insight as to why this might be the case?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AK3ss.png]

Comment: It does not appear that the support for g++ compilation exists.  Did you install the compiler in a custom directory?  Try: ls -l  /usr/lib/*++*  This should show files  with names like libcstd++.so.3    If not the libraries are not installed or are not where the linker (ld) can find them.  You did compile it on Solaris first, right?  You cannot copy an executable from one OS to another.  And have them run correctly.

Comment: A little background: The Solaris machine that I'm running this on is a virtual machine hosted and ran by my work. I don't have super-user access, and when I logged onto the machine, it recognized the command g++, but it didn't have a manual entry for it, so it seems like the libraries aren't, as you suggested, installed. I'll take a look and see if I can figure a way to install them.

And to answer your second question, yes, I am compiling direct from Solaris.

Comment: It looks like the gcc/g++ installation is broken. __cxa_atexit should be found within one of the standard libs that are linked by default.

Comment: look for the 'gcc-c++-runtime' package using 'pkg search' command. Once you install that you should have the libstd++.so in case you dont.